# I keep getting certificate errors and websites not loading correctly or really slow

Tags: windows-10, firefox, certificate

It all started when I changed the "Internet Time Settings" server to something else because it didn't get the correct time.

After I have found a correct server the time was correct (**also is now**), and now almost every site I get into that has https is displaying error about the certificate:

> Your connection is not secure

I am using Firefox and it happens in Explorer and Chrome too..

My computer is new (bought it 2 month ago) and I just installed windows 10 (clean install).

What could be the problem?

I don't have the tools to test the CMOS (saw an answer about that) and I don't *think* that it is it because the computer is new..

I tried manually change the time back to 2015 and back to 2016 but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: By the way, I looked every where and tested everything I saw except the CMOS, everyone said that the problem is with the clock and obviously it is, it started with it, but the time is correct so what can I do now :\

**Edit2**: Also, there is a problem with loading some pages..:
(Amazon for example)
[image]

Comment: If you boot into the firmware shell.  What year does it think it is?

Comment: what is firmware shell? do you mean the bios?

Comment: @Ramhound If it is the bios, the time there is correct

Comment: What security software do you have installed?  What certificate does your browser believe it receives if you go to say, https://www.google.com, a screenshot works best for this type of information.

Comment: @Ramhound I have installed NOD32 and Malwarebytes (just installed it..).
google.com works fine, I entered piriform.com for example And got this error:
Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_NOT_YET_VALID_ISSUER_CERTIFICATE

Comment: confirm your date is in the right year. I remember once I beat my head against an issue for hours before I realized that the date was correct, except for the last char. A not-yet-valid error implies that the computers date is far in the past.

Comment: @FrankThomas Believe me I have checked multiple times :\ It is 2016 I thought I was losing it because everyone was saying that lol..

Comment: I need the information I requested.  I want to know what certificate is being presented on a site that is presenting a certificate error.  If it's not google choose a webpage that does.  Your Amazon screenshot tells me your SSL content is being blocked by your security software though

Comment: @Ramhound I am not entirely sure what information you want, I got this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a4353959a2defb5504762076fe1947a is it ok? or I am not understanding you correctly

Comment: I want to know what certificate Firefox believes pitform.com is sending it.  Firefox believes that the certificate is invalid.  I want to compare the certificate I receive to the certificate you receive.  The github information does provide the required information I am seeking.

Comment: @Ramhound Think I found it: http://pasteboard.co/9UvB9wZcW.png

Comment: You have Nod32 to configure to scan your SSL by using its Man In The Middle attack feature to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a documented issue with eset nod32 AV. Disable https scanning by following the instructions in the "Disable SSL protocol scanning" section.

[HTTPS websites fail to load or you receive the error message "Connection is untrusted" when using your web browser with ESET products](http://support.eset.com/kb3126/?locale=en_US)

There are further instructions to repair that capability on the same page; but I would confirm it's the issue first, which seems pretty likely since you say you just installed it.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realized that was the anti-virus!

Comment: It happens with a few different AV suites - it happened to me with avast.

Comment: I wonder why it does that.. And if there is a way around disabling it, before I reinstalled Windows 10 I had NOD32 but didn't came across this problem

Comment: It does that because the security software is literally a man in the middle between all secure http traffic in order to scan not, it's by design, but the very nature of how it has to be designed break all secure http connections

Comment: Your likely didn't have the feature enabled before